# Tensorflow detection model zoo

Tags: python, tensorflow

I managed to train a CNN with the `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco` model which has to detect shards in static, grayscale slow motion camera images. I read that this model is fast but has a low accuracy. So I wonder if there is a model better suited for my problem.

Here are 6 images, which are tested by tensorflow. As you can see the model can't detect the last 2 images. The shards on the last 2 images can barely or not at all be seen by human eye but they are there.

Tensorflow provides these open source models: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

Which model of the tensorflow zoo would you recommend for this job. Does a documentation of all models exist that I can look up?

Also: If this is the wrong place to ask this question, would you please recommend me a better place?

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Tensorflow detection model zoo (the link you gave) now shows all the accuracies (in mAP) of all available models... yours has 21 mAP. maybe try ssd_resnet_50_fpn_coco model (35 mAP)? it is balanced in speed & performance tradeoff. That being said, still not too sure how models will perform on things the human eye can't even detect. your training set should have these instances for it to learn. do you get many false positives?